# How to hide a column in .tpl file?

Tags: html

[image]

My client does not want to show the 3rd column: SKU. How do I do that? Here is the code:

```
{foreach from=$customization.fields item="field"}
     <div class="product-customization-line row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 label">
               {**$field.label*}
            </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-8 value">
                    {if $field.type == 'text'}
                      {if (int)$field.id_module}

                          {$field.text nofilter}

                      {else}

                          {$field.text}

                      {/if}
                    {elseif $field.type == 'image'}
                      <img src="{$field.image.small.url}">
                    {/if}
                  </div>
            </div>
       {/foreach}
```

It is in a language I don't understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code and template you have. Also ask the original author of the template how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```html
{foreach from=$customization.fields item="field"}
    <div class="product-customization-line row" {if $field.label == 'SKU'}style="display: none"{/if}>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 label">
         {**$field.label*}
      </div>
          <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-8 value">
              {if $field.type == 'text'}
                {if (int)$field.id_module}

                    {$field.text nofilter}

                {else}

                    {$field.text}

                {/if}
              {elseif $field.type == 'image'}
                <img src="{$field.image.small.url}">
              {/if}
            </div>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
<style>

.page-cart table tr th:nth-child(3) {
display: none;
}

.page-cart table tr td:nth-child(3) {
display: none;
}

</style>
```